# jquery not working locally when tested

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to redirect to new web page after a message is displayed for certain amount of time on the dialog box.
My code is not working, please correct me. I cannot see a dialog box when I run locally.

**test.html**

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($("#alert").length) {
    var title;
    if ($("#alert span").length) {
        title = $("#alert span").text();
    }
    $("#alert div").dialog({
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        open: function() { var foo = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
               foo.dialog('close');
            }, 2000);
            window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        }

    });
}
 });

</script>
<body>
<div id="alert">
<span>Password change</span>
<div>Password was successfully changed.</div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have jQuery UI javascript and CSS loaded to trigger the dialog function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jQuery-UI to use the dialog function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#alert").length) {
        var title;
        if ($("#alert span").length) {
            title = $("#alert span").text();
        }
        $("#alert div").dialog({
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            open: function() {
                var foo = $(this);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    foo.dialog('close');
                }, 2000);
                //window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
  
<body>
    <div id="alert">
        <span>Password change</span>
        <div>Password was successfully changed.</div>
    </div>
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!- I've added this. ->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: In IE, its not showing any jquery dialog box. Do I need to add any thing to make it work in IE? thanks.

Comment: Or is their any way using alert box I can redirect to new page after timeout or when user clicks on ok button which is on alert box instead of using jquery??

Comment: I copied the same above code and named as test.html and tried to run on my machine, but cannot see the dialog box. But in the above code snippet I can see the dialog box. Coming to alert box, I want to display the alert box for only certain time(5 seconds) , user may click ok within 5 seconds or after 5 seconds the page should redirect to new page as doing in above code snippet. After certain time the dialog closes automatically and redirects the page (window.location.href = "..";
). As I'm aware we cannot make alert box disappear after certain amount of time without user interaction

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are hosting the html file and all locally, localhost.

Perhaps use nodejs or even use IIS to host them and then open the files from there.